# Client-server different language and OS

Tags: java, c, linux, windows, sockets

I'm trying to modify a client-server program so that I can connect to the server(which I run in VirtualBox on Linux) which is written in C, from a client which I want to run in Windows, and is written in Java.

I have a few problems though. Here is my server.c file which I run on Linux:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <string.h>

void deservire_client(int c) {
  // serving the client
  int nr, i=2, nrDiv=0, sirDiv[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  recv(c, &nr, sizeof(nr), MSG_WAITALL);
  while ( i <= nr/2){
            if ( nr%i == 0){
                sirDiv[nrDiv]=i;
                nrDiv+=1;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
  send(c, &sirDiv, sizeof(sirDiv), 0);
  close(c);
  // ending of serving the client;
}

int main() {
  int s;
  struct sockaddr_in server, client;
  int c, l;

  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (s < 0) {
    printf("Creating server socket error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_port = htons(1234);
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    printf("Binding Error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  listen(s, 5);

  l = sizeof(client);
  memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));

  while (1) {
    c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &l);
    printf("S-a conectat un client.\n");
    if (fork() == 0) { // fiu
      deservire_client(c);
      return 0;
    }

  }
}
```

As you can see, the server will return an array of integers, which will be the divisors of the number I send in from the client file.

I have written a client file, also in C, just to see if it works. I run them both under Linux though. Here's the file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  char send_data[1024];


  c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (c < 0) {
    printf("Creating client socket error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_port = htons(1234);
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  if (connect(c, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    printf("Connecting to server error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while(1){
    int nr, sirDiv[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, i=0;
    printf("\nInput number: ");   scanf("%d",&nr);
    send(c ,&nr, sizeof(nr), 0);
    recv(c, &sirDiv, sizeof(sirDiv), 0);

    printf("\nThe divisors are:\n");
    while( i <= 10 ){
      if ( sirDiv[i] <= nr/2 && sirDiv[i] != 0)
        printf("%d ",sirDiv[i]);
      i+=1;
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Ask client if he wants to close
    printf("\nq or Q to exit: ");
    scanf("%s",send_data);
    if (strcmp(send_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(send_data , "Q") == 0) {
      close(c);
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So this works fine under Linux, and I can connect multiple clients to the server. Now I want to create a client and write it in Java. Here's an example that has been given to me and that I'm trying to modify:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client2 {

    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 1234;
    private static final int UNSIGNED_SHORT_MAX_VALUE = 65535;
    private static final int UNSIGNED_SHORT_MIN_VALUE = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
            int a = readUnsignedShort("a = ", reader);
            int b = readUnsignedShort("b = ", reader);
            writeIntegersToSocket(a, b, socket);
            readIntegersSumFromSocket(socket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cautgh exception " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeStreams(socket,reader);
        }
    }

    private static void readIntegersSumFromSocket(Socket c) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream socketIn = new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream());
        int s = socketIn.readUnsignedShort();
        System.out.println("s = " + s);
    }

    private static void writeIntegersToSocket(int a, int b, Socket c) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream socketOut = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
        socketOut.writeShort(a);
        socketOut.writeShort(b);
        socketOut.flush();
    }

    private static int readUnsignedShort(String message, BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        int unsignedShortNumber = 0;
        System.out.print(message);
        try {
            unsignedShortNumber = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (unsignedShortNumber < UNSIGNED_SHORT_MIN_VALUE || unsignedShortNumber > UNSIGNED_SHORT_MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given number must be unsigned short [0..65535]!");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("The given input is not an integer!");
        }
        return unsignedShortNumber;
    }

    private static void closeStreams(Socket socket, BufferedReader reader) {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not close socket!");
            }
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not close reader!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This example was made for a client-server program which lets the user input two numbers, and the server will return the sum. I have a few problems when I'm trying to modify it though.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Socket socket = null;
        int i = 0;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
            int nr = readUnsignedShort("nr = ", reader);
            while(int i <=10)
                int sirDiv[i] = readUnsignedShort("b = ", reader);//Here I have an error, type mismatch, how do I fix this?
            writeIntegersToSocket(nr, sirDiv, socket);//Again, how do I write this instead?
            readIntegersSumFromSocket(socket);

private static void writeIntegersToSocket(int a, int b, Socket c) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream socketOut = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
        socketOut.writeShort(nr);
        socketOut.writeShort(nrDiv); //will probably have an error here as well
        socketOut.flush();
    }
```

Apart from these type mismatches, I still don't know how to connect to the server which I run on linux as in, what do I have to change, the SERVER_ADDRESS or something? Pinging localhost in Linux gives me 127.0.0.1 and pinging 'ping -4 localhost' in Windows gives me the same thing. Could anyone give me a few pointers with this? I've been trying all day.

Comment: The `localhost` alias is always the *local* host, it's the loopback interface. You need to use some other command to find out the list of available interfaces and their addresses.

Comment: I mean I'm running both Windows and Linux under the same machine, and the Virtual Box Linux Network is attached to NAT(Network Address Translation), which will mean they share the same IP(I think). Trying to change it to Bridged Adapter made me not be able to access the internet from Linux.

Comment: This question is actually not about programming at all but about basic networking, i.e. which IP addresses can be used to access a server on one system from another system (127.0.0.1 will not work). I recommend to reduce the question to this problem (i.e. remove all the code which is not needed for this question) and instead ask on superuser.com.

Comment: In Windows you can use the network configuration to find out the addresses. In Linux you can use the [`ip`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) command.

Comment: I mean as far as I can tell my IP address in Linux is 10.0.2.15, and I tried connecting to that, but I get a Connection timed out exception. Doesn't the fact that the operating systems and the server/client programs are on the same laptop change anything?

Comment: I recommend using commands like `ping`, `netcat`, and `telnet` to verify connectivity between your aspiring client and server systems.  Then, once you're sure you can pass TCP packets, try debugging your own fledgling client and server.

Comment: Alright, seems I cannot ping my virtual machine. Think I have to change my network settings on my virtual machine to bridge connections.

Comment: Alright, finally got it to work, thanks a lot for helping me get here. Now only the type mismatch errors remain.